# How to get a value from JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Here we have a JSON  file:

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"Potato and Cheese Frittata",
      "href":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Potato-and-Cheese-Frittata/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients":"cheddar cheese, eggs, olive oil, onions, potato, salt",
      "thumbnail":"http://img.recipepuppy.com/2.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "title":"Eggnog Thumbprints",
      "href":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Eggnog-Thumbprints/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients":"brown sugar, butter, butter, powdered sugar, eggs, flour, nutmeg, rum, salt, vanilla extract, sugar",
      "thumbnail":"http://img.recipepuppy.com/3.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "title":"Irish Champ",
      "href":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Irish-Champ/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients":"black pepper, butter, green onion, milk, potato, salt",
      "thumbnail":"http://img.recipepuppy.com/5.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "title":"Chocolate-Cherry Thumbprints",
      "href":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Chocolate-Cherry-Thumbprints/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients":"cocoa powder, baking powder, butter, eggs, flour, oats, salt, sugar, vanilla extract",
      "thumbnail":"http://img.recipepuppy.com/6.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "title":"Hot Spiced Cider",
      "href":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Hot-Spiced-Cider/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients":"allspice, apple cider, brown sugar, cinnamon, cloves, nutmeg, orange, salt",
      "thumbnail":"http://img.recipepuppy.com/8.jpg"
   }
]
```

How can i get only the `titles` of each `results`
for example here I need to get only ( Potato and Cheese Frittata, Eggnog Thumbprints, Chocolate-Cherry Thumbprints,Hot Spiced Cider)

Thank you!

Comment: how would you get one from regular javascript object ? how do you convert json to javascript object?

Comment: It isn't json, it is an object (perhaps parsed from JSON). Use the native .map function on it.

Comment: @Travis J you are right this is pared JSON output, but I thought it is also JSON, if not what is that? and how to use .map function? can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/14gege58/)***

First, JSON is a string notation used for serializing information. It can be deserialized (parsed in JavaScript) into an object or array. What you have is the deserialized format, and as a result it is simply a plain array of objects.

As a result, the native [`.map`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) api function will work to map the .title from each object into an array of just those titles.

```
var titles = result.map(function(obj){ return obj.title; });
```

Comment: @Chris - `result` is your JavaScript array of objects as shown in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give you what you want:

```
var a = [{ "title":"Potato and Cheese Frittata"}, {"title":"Eggnog Thumbprints" }]; 
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
    alert(a[i].title); 
}
```